# Activities past due dates are still displaying in Next Steps section in LEX

Tags: lightning-experience, tasks, activities

I am observing that the activities that past the due date are still displaying in the Next steps section in Lightning Experience. Please see the screenshot below.

Is this a normal behavior?

What I have to do in order to move it to Past Activities section? Please, I need experts answer. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you'll notice the dates are highlighted in red, which indicates that they are open tasks that are past due. This same behavior happens in Classic as well on places where you can view open tasks (e.g. Open Activities). To get them to move out of the Next Steps area, they need to be marked as "Completed".